# Run mongo script in deployed docker swarm container

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-swarm

I have deployed a database using docker swarm

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml app
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  database:
    image: mongo:latest
```

I'd like to run a JavaScript file `script.js` from my host in the deployed `database` container:

```
docker exec \
    app_database.1.$(docker service ps -f 'name=app_database.1' app_database -q) \
    mongo script.js
```

However, the file `script.js` does not exist in the container (only on my host). How can I run it without restarting the `database` service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A script can be sent on stdin to the `mongo` client.

Create a script locally:

```
print('The mongodb version is: '+db.version())
```

Then run

```
$ cat script.js | docker exec $container mongo --quiet
The mongodb version is: 3.6.3
```